# What methods or patterns can be used for rendering UI components based on supplied array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, socket.io

I'm currently playing about with node.js and am looking to find a neater method for rendering a list based on an array returned to the client through an event.

In my sample application, the node server emits a 'details-changed' event which passes a simple array.  At the UI end, I consume that event and render a list item for each of the array elements.

At present, I am deleting all list items and recreating them all based on the returned array.  However, I would like to know if there is a more efficient method or pattern where existing items remain and only new items created and missing items removed.

Comment: Well, of course, you could write code to figure out what changed and only update the changed items.  But, we can't really help with that in any way without seeing your code and your UI.  You can send only changed info from the server or you can figure out what has actually changed from the data and only modify changed items.  Or, you can just decide it's easiest and just as fast to just recreate all the items each time.  That's all up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ReactJS for handling UI updates based on the data changes from server side. It would be the best approach for manipulating the DOM updates efficiently and neatly.